# Why does an azure function with TimerTrigger and Task<IActionResult> not work?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have several Azure Functions running with Http Triggers, and they are all set up like

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "GAdminRemoveEntry")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {...
```

But now I need a Timer Trigger Azure Function, and adding the TimerTrigger attribute does not work.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
            ILogger log)
        {
```

The function shows up as a Timer trigger, and the timer settings shows up correctly in the Integration tab. I did not fi.

The function looks like this:

```
    public class TestTimerTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("TestTimerTrigger")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("TestTimerTrigger");
            await BlobStorageHelper.WriteWebview("somefile", "somedata");
            return new OkObjectResult("all good!");
        }
    }
```

The above function does not execute, nor would I be able to call it manually from the Code + Test tab. I did not see any errors during building, deploying, or executing.

[image: the integration tab of the functionin azure portal]
[image: the edit timer popup showing the cron string]

**But...** shortly after beginning this post, I was able to get it to work by removing the IActionResult type, and the return command. This is okay in this instance, but I do not understand why that is necessary.

The function now looks like this, but my question stands: why did it not work initially?

```
    public class TestTimerTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("TestTimerTrigger")]
        public async Task Run(
            [TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("TestTimerTrigger");
            await BlobStorageHelper.WriteWebview("somefile", "somedata");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IActionResult` is typically used in HTTP-triggered functions to represent an HTTP response that the function will return. It allows to specify the status code, headers, and content of the HTTP response.

However, for non-HTTP-triggered functions, such as Timer Trigger functions, there's no need to return an `IActionResult` because Time trigger functions are not invoked via HTTP requests and don't need to return HTTP responses. Instead, it performs background tasks or jobs based on a schedule.

Timer Trigger function;

```cs
public class Function
{
    [FunctionName("Function")]
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

## `OUTPUT`:

**Local :**

```
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-16T04:23:05.319Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000116B5F66'.
[2024-02-16T04:25:00.120Z] Executing 'Function' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-02-16T09:55:00.0668667+05:30', Id=c36a4e00-5483-45f3-a078-f72d7762ef6c)
[2024-02-16T04:25:00.142Z] C# Timer trigger function executed at: 2/16/2024 9:55:00 AM
[2024-02-16T04:25:00.167Z] Executed 'Function' (Succeeded, Id=c36a4e00-5483-45f3-a078-f72d7762ef6c, Duration=89ms)
```

[image]

**Azure :**

```
2024-02-16 04:40:00.026

Executing 'Function' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-02-16T04:40:00.0124959+00:00', Id=4b8c5990-16f5-4ee9-91b7-87d9e3951ce3)

Information

2024-02-16 04:40:00.038

C# Timer trigger function executed at: 2/16/2024 4:40:00 AM

Information

2024-02-16 04:40:00.053

Executed 'Function' (Succeeded, Id=4b8c5990-16f5-4ee9-91b7-87d9e3951ce3, Duration=34ms)

Information
```

[image]

Comment: that does make sense, though it would be nice if it was documented that it will just not trigger by time if you use this return value.